# ASP.NET 4 Routing and Performance Issues

Tags: asp.net, performance, routes

I am successfully using **asp.net routing functionality (web forms)** locally with VS 2010 and it's default web server and on a live 2003 IIS 6 machine. However, I am having performance issues where the each page takes 2 seconds to load. If I disable routing in Global.asax, then the site runs fine.

Is anyone else having **performance issues** with asp.net 4 web form routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am returning to answer the question of routing performance. There was not an issue with asp.net routing at all. After running a trace and doing some digging, I found that it was the AJAX ScriptManager that was causing my delays.

Routing is working great with asp.net webforms running on a 2003 IIS 6 machine after testing since the original post was made!